# PyPDF2 does not always extract text from pdf file

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to extract text from a PDF file using the python package `PyPDF2`. Below is the code I wrote for it and it is working just fine for most pdf files. However for [this file](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S1350946221000951?token=61AE66759FBB62AC2BA33F8E8D9A301D17DA0411E67C78EE0A4D57EBAE3C5B1A7DBB11168B1B9FAAEB16350CCA058B82&originRegion=us-east-1&originCreation=20220222011046) I get the following error and no text gets extracted whatsoever. Here the warning: `PdfReadWarning: Xref table not zero-indexed. ID numbers for objects will be corrected. [pdf.py:1736]`

```
import PyPDF2

# Import and read pdf file
file_name = 'path/to/file.pdf'
pdfFileObj = open(file_name, 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj, strict=True)

# Extract text from pdf file
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(1)
text = pageObj.extractText()
print(text)
```

Comment: it is reasonable because i think there's no tool that can 100% convert and pdf to text. ocr always has a possibility.